# asp.net C# uploading big file and processing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to be able to upload file from my .aspx page to my web server so that it can be preocessed into a different format.

e.g. user will upload a doc and in few seconds it would see a pdf version of the doc on the web page.

I have web service available which can convert doc to pdf.

now

1- how do i automate upload + conversion process.

2- how do i handle big files here.

3- how not to make user wait for all this thing to happen.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a FILEUPLOAD control in your webpage and process it in the postback ([article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx))
2. Set up your web application in IIS to handle bigger files ([article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383781/increase-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis6))
3. The user does have to wait for the upload and the conversion. The trick is to give adequate feedback, so the user doesn't get the feeling the browser is not responding. This can vary from a "Please wait while uploading" message to a timer animation or even a progress bar.

Use [this article](http://aspalliance.com/1442) for more information about setting up a responsive file upload.