# Strange content length value received from IE8/9 browser in upload request

Tags: file-upload, http-headers

I am facing a problem of moving 4+GB size file between computers. First I couldn't move the file on micro SD card ([see my other post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17220/do-memory-cards-have-any-max-file-size-limitation))

So now I am trying to upload this file. Exact file size is 4549809009, so when I try to upload it, my upload fails at premature ending of a input file.

Here are headers I get:

```
POST /webfolder/webapp/Folder/MediaChest HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer: http://myotherhost/webfolder/webapp/Folder/MediaChest
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7db2ce294006e4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: myotherhost
Content-Length: 254842353
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

So why content length set as 254842353? IE continues uploading after reaching this size, however the upload receiver thinks that end of stream reached. Where is problem, in the receiver or the sender?

Answer (score 0):

One question I would have is, what is hosting the other site? If it is an Asp.Net site hosted by IIS, you will probably need to make sure that the maxRequestLength property in the web.config is set to handle a POST that big.

See:
[Increase file upload size limit in iis6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383781/increase-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis6)

Comment: The headers are coming from IE side, so no interference with hosting. It was my first guess that hosting messed up with headers, however it works correctly, check it tjws.sf.net