# asp.net - How to catch an error occurring before PreInit?

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm having a strange problem while uploading a simple text file.

I have this page with an asp:Upload control, and nothing more.

This upload works with every file, except one. Ok, the file might be corrupted, no problem with that. The thing is, nothing seems to run. It don't fall into any event (including PreInit), nor redirects to my custom error page.

Does anyone has gone into this? Is there any way I can catch this error, at least to show a message that an error occurred?

My error page is defined in web config: `<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" />`

(Unfortunately, I can't share this file, as it contains sensitive information, like phone, name, address, etc)

Comment: Please post the error message you receive.

Comment: Have you tried turning custom errors off in your web.config? The ugly red/white/yellow message will give you a stack trace and whatnot to help you debug.

Comment: Even disabling, no error at all. Browser gives a message that the server have not responded (any browser, tryed with Opera, IE, Firefox, Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is occurring on the client side, even before the server is hit ? You could try putting on a Fiddler trace to see if there is a http request and response.

Comment: Checked with Dragonfly, it's sending the request, but no response

Comment: Is there any error logged in the windows event log on the server ? You could also check the IIS logs to see if the request made it to IIS. Could there be some firewall/antivirus which might be blocking the request ?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, you may need to specify the MaxRequestLength property in your web.config file to specify a high upper limit for uploads (see: [Increase file upload size limit in iis6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383781/increase-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis6))

If it's not that, check your IIS logs to see what is going on. The fact that you're not getting an ASP.NET error message leads me to believe that IIS is falling over somewhere. The logs should give you a clue as to why.