# requestFiltering equivalent in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

What is the equivalent of this in IIS 6.0 (The web.config code below works in IIS 7.5)

```
<system.webServer> 
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="xxx"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLScan is the tool for IIS 6,

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/working-with-urlscan/common-urlscan-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer to this question:  [Increase file upload size limit in iis6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383781/increase-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis6)

Anything in `<system.webServer>` is used by IIS 7 and above; IIS 6 does not know what to do with those configurations.  Stick to attributes in the `<system.web>` element for IIS versions below 7.